# Logic issue in powershell if statement

Tags: powershell, if-statement, logic

Not sure why but my if statement not go on the proper direction, in the following example one interface is disabled but it still shows the True value, however it should show the False one.

I have the following interfaces:

```
get-netadapter

Name                      InterfaceDescription                    ifIndex Status       MacAddress             LinkSpeed
----                      --------------------                    ------- ------       ----------             ---------
Embedded FlexibleLOM ...2 HPE FlexFabric 10Gb 4-port 536FLR-...#2      10 Disabled     08-xxx-62        10 Gbps
Embedded FlexibleLOM ...1 HPE FlexFabric 10Gb 4-port 536FLR-...#4      11 Up           08-xxx-60        10 Gbps
```

You can see one is disabled.
This is the script:

```
$vmswitch1stinterface = (Get-VMSwitchTeam -Name "Teaming").NetAdapterInterfaceDescription|select -first 1
$vmswitch2ndinterface = (Get-VMSwitchTeam -Name "Teaming").NetAdapterInterfaceDescription|select -last 1
$1stinterfacestatus = Get-NetAdapter -InterfaceDescription $vmswitch1stinterface|select Status
$2ndinterfacestatus = Get-NetAdapter -InterfaceDescription $vmswitch2ndinterface|select Status
if (($1stinterfacestatus -and $2ndinterfacestatus) -eq 'up') 
{
    Write-Host "OK: NIC ports are up (VMSwitch)"
    Exit 0
}   else 
{
    Write-Host "WARNING: An interface is down! Please check in the list which one is not UP:" 
    Get-NetAdapter -InterfaceDescription $vmswitch1stinterface|Select-Object InterfaceDescription, Status
    Get-NetAdapter -InterfaceDescription $vmswitch2ndinterface|Select-Object InterfaceDescription, Status
    Exit 1
}
```

The values are as follow for easy determination:

```
$vmswitch1stinterface: HPE FlexFabric 10Gb 4-port 536FLR-T Adapter #4
$vmswitch2ndinterface: HPE FlexFabric 10Gb 4-port 536FLR-T Adapter #2
$1stinterfacestatus

Status
------
Up

$2ndinterfacestatus

Status
------
Disabled
```

The result of this script is the following which is not correct:

```
OK: NIC ports are up (VMSwitch)
```

What I'm missing in the logic?

Comment: I think you meant `if (($1stinterfacestatus.status -eq 'up' -and $2ndinterfacestatus.status -eq 'up'))`

Comment: @AbdulNiyasPM Could you please provide your suggestion as an answer instead?

Comment: yes, this is what I want thank you very much, so in powershell has to mention 2 times the condition

Answer (score 0):

`$1stinterfacestatus` and `$2ndinterfacestatus` are [PSCustomObjects](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/powershell/scripting/learn/deep-dives/everything-about-pscustomobject?view=powershell-7.2#creating-a-pscustomobject) and it can have properties. In your case both objects has `Status` property which you can access it using `.` notation.(ie, `$yourPSCustomObject.Status`).

I think you intended to test if both interfaces are up, which you can do by

```
if (($1stinterfacestatus.status -eq 'up' -and $2ndinterfacestatus.status -eq 'up')) {
    Write-Output "Both interfaces are up"
}
```